# La chaleur qu'il a fait(e?)

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé, pronoms-impersonnels

Je ne parviens pas à trouver la formule correcte pour cette phrase :

- *A cause de la chaleur qu'il a **fait**, j'ai dû renoncer à ma promenade.*
- *A cause de la chaleur qu'il a **faite**, j'ai dû renoncer à ma promenade.*

En effet, je me rappelle avoir toujours utilisé à l'oral la première forme, mais je pense aussi au contre exemple suivant : *A cause de la boulette qu'il a **faite**, ...*

Quelle est la forme correcte ? Et quelle règle s'applique ? Je me dis que le "il" impersonnel fonctionne différemment du "il" personnel, mais sans certitudes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

En fait, la différence est que le "il" est personnel ou impersonnel.

1. **Exemple 1**

> A cause de la chaleur qu'**il** a fait, j'ai dû renoncer à ma promenade.

Le sujet est **il**, et il est impersonnel (c'est la même chose que "il fait beau"... personne ne fait beau...). On ne peut pas le remplacer par "Jean". On ne dit pas (à moins que Jean ne soit une source de chaleur dans la pièce, mais cela change le sens...)

> A cause de la chaleur que **Jean** a fait(e), j'ai dû renoncer à ma promenade.

Le **il** est donc **impersonnel**, donc on n'[accorde pas](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-des-verbes-impersonnels-187.php).

2. **Exemple 2**

> A cause de la boulette qu'**il** a faite

Le sujet est toujours **il**, mais cette fois cela représente une **personne**, on peut remplacer par "Jean"

> A cause de la boulette que **Jean** a faite

On [accorde](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/grammaire-accord-participe-passe.php) donc le participe passé car le **COD** est avant le verbe (il a fait quoi ? une boulette)

Answer (score 2):

On dit

> La chaleur qu'il a fait.

Voici le [lien](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/capsules/2663.htm) qui explique pourquoi.

Answer (score 0):

Je ne connais pas la règle, mais en tant que Français, "A cause de la chaleur qu'il a fait, j'ai dû renoncer à ma promenade" me semble être la bonne réponse.

Comment: C'est comme ça que tout le monde dit apparemment, mais je cherche vraiment à mettre le doigt sur la règle